# Paraxial wave equation solution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I am looking for a worked solution to the paraxial wave equation, since most sources just say that *clearly* Gaussians are solutions but they do not explicitly show so.

This equation is equivalent to the TDSE for a free particle, if we replace *z* by *t*.

$$\frac{\partial^2 \Psi(x,y,t)}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2 \Psi(x,y,t)}{\partial^2 y} = 2ik\frac{\partial \Psi(x,y,t)}{\partial t} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE you have written is non other than the heat equation with proportionality constant $\alpha = 2 i k$. Typically it can be solved using Green's function techniques, which you can see on Wikipedia.

In any case, the reason they probably say $\textit{clearly}$ is because you can solve the 1+1-dimensional ($\frac {\partial \Psi} {\partial y} = 0$) equation by using Fourier series and seperation of variables. Fourier series are naturally composed of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, i.e, exponentials which resemble Gaussians to some extent. The natural attempt to generalise this to the higher $2+1$ (or $n+1$) dimensional case is then to assume the $\textit{ansatz}$ of a Gaussian and see if it solves it.

Edit: To actually know your Fourier series solution is the Gaussian one is a bit tricky, I'm unsure of the best way to see this except an ad-hoc expansion of your Gaussian and a matching procedure.